# PHPStorm: No intend by twig closing tag

Tags: ide, twig, phpstorm

PHPStorm4 doesn't know twig very good. It doesn't detect closing tags:

```
{% block header %}
    {% endblock header %}
```

but I want:

```
{% block header %}
{% endblock header %}
```

I already tried to set intend in the general code settings to 0 but this doesn't work...

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig support is very limited right now, we hope to improve it in PhpStorm 5.0. I've created a [new bug in the issue tracker for this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11473), feel free to star/vote.